# ActionListener not working in Java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have created a JPanel over JFrame and added a JButon and JLabel to the JPanel. But the ActionlListener does not seems work. When i click on JButton, Nothing Happens. Please someone Help me. Thanks in Advance.
Here is my code

```
public class Trials implements ActionListener {

    JButton scoreButton;
    JLabel score;
    JPanel MyPanel;
    int ScoreAmount=0;

    public JPanel createPanel()
    {
        JPanel MyPanel =new JPanel();
        MyPanel.setLayout(null);
        MyPanel.setSize(50, 50);
        MyPanel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        JLabel score =new JLabel(""+ScoreAmount);
        score.setSize(50, 50);
        score.setLocation(250,50);
        score.setForeground(Color.red);
        MyPanel.add(score);         
        JButton scoreButton =new JButton("add");
        scoreButton.setSize(100, 50);
        scoreButton.setLocation(100,50);
        scoreButton.setBackground(Color.red);
        scoreButton.addActionListener(this);
        MyPanel.add(scoreButton);           
        MyPanel.setOpaque(true);
        MyPanel.setVisible(true);
        return MyPanel;         
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      if(e.getSource()==scoreButton)
      {
            ScoreAmount = ScoreAmount+1;
            score.setText(""+ScoreAmount);              
      }
    }

    public static void display()
    {
        JFrame MyFrame = new JFrame();
        Trials tr =new Trials();
        MyFrame.setContentPane(tr.createPanel());
        MyFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        MyFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            display();
                        }
                });
        }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you shadowing local variables declared for `public class Trials implements ActionListener {`

```
JButton scoreButton;
JLabel score;
JPanel MyPanel;
int ScoreAmount=0;
```

should be in `public JPanel createPanel()`

```
MyPanel = new JPanel();
score = new JLabel("" + ScoreAmount);
scoreButton = new JButton("add");
```

not

```
JPanel MyPanel = new JPanel();
JLabel score = new JLabel("" + ScoreAmount);
JButton scoreButton = new JButton("add");
```

---

- remove  `MyPanel.setLayout(null);`, default `FlowLayout` implemented in `JPanel` do that by default, then add `JComponents` to `JPanel` only `MyPanel.add(componentVariable)` witout any `sizing` for `JPanel`s childs
- call `MyFrame.pack()` instead of `MyFrame.setSize(500, 500);`

Comment: +1, though it might not be obvious to someone who didn't spot it first.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. As a beginner, its great getting knowledge about "shadowing local variables"

Answer (score 0):

When you define your score button you do not assign the class level field, instead you create a new local variable.

```
JButton scoreButton =new JButton("add");
scoreButton.setSize(100, 50);
scoreButton.setLocation(100,50);
scoreButton.setBackground(Color.red);
scoreButton.addActionListener(this);
MyPanel.add(scoreButton);
```

Should become:

```
this.scoreButton =new JButton("add");
scoreButton.setSize(100, 50);
scoreButton.setLocation(100,50);
scoreButton.setBackground(Color.red);
scoreButton.addActionListener(this);
MyPanel.add(scoreButton);
```

So when the actionPerformed method is called the scoreButton is probably null